# Kubernetes Horizontal and Vertical Pod autoscaling togather

Tags: kubernetes, containers, autoscaling

We are trying out Kubernetes Autoscaling options. We have configured for Horizontal Pod Autoscaling but was wondering if it is possible to implement both horizontal and vertical auto scaling condition for a particular application ? to explain more I want to be able to increase resource of a pod if I don't want to increase the number of pods and if I don't want to increase the pod resources I will be able to increase the number of pods to scale for the same application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible to set both Horizontal and Vertical Pod Autoscaling options. You will have to just set the resource limits appropriately. Here's an example:

1. You configure a pod resource `request` for `300m` CPU and `limit` for `800m` CPU. This will configure the VPA to allow the pod to have `300m->800m` of CPU.
2. Then you configure HPA to scale-out if pod CPU is `800m`.

Now, what will happen is, the pod will scale vertically, for up to `0.8` vCPU cores, and once it reaches that point, the horizontal auto scaler will kick in and spawn a new pod, and the existing pod will be limited to 0.8vCPU.

[Here](https://www.kubecost.com/kubernetes-autoscaling/kubernetes-vpa/) is a good resource on understanding a VPA setup and getting started with one.

Of course if you want your scaling to be driven by a custom metric, other than vCPU or memory, you will need a custom HPA or VPA controller in your cluster.

This is used a lot and is a very common design pattern :)

Answer (score 9):

If your HPA is not based on CPU or Memory you can do this with no problem, but this is not recommended to use both VPA and HPA when the HPA is based on CPU or Memory.

Taken from the [VPA documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler#known-limitations): *"Vertical Pod Autoscaler should not be used with the Horizontal Pod Autoscaler (HPA) on CPU or memory at this moment"*

There are some options on how to do so. For example, you can update the HPA relatively to the CPU/Memory change.

For further examples, there is a free tool named [gMaestro](https://granulate.io/gmaestro/?utm_source=stackoverflow&utm_medium=forum&utm_campaign=gMaestro) that supports both rightsizing and HPA, you can try to use it.